# Merge rows with duplications in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
   species family     Events       groups
1     SP1      A      10,22           G1
2     SP1      B          7           G2
3     SP1    C,D  4,5,6,1,3  G3,G4,G5,G6
4     SP2      A      22,10           G1
5     SP2    D,C  6,5,4,3,1  G4,G6,G5,G3
6     SP3      C  4,5,3,6,1     G3,G6,G5
7     SP3      E          7           G2
8     SP3      A         10           G1
9     SP4      C       7,22          G12
```

and I would like to simply merge row for each where there is at least one duplicated element in each columns (except `species`).

For instance I will merge the rows :

```
species family    Events      groups
SP1      A        10,22       G1
species family    Events      groups
SP2      A        22,10       G1
species family    Events      groups
SP3      A        10          G1
```

into

```
species      family    Events      groups
SP1,SP2,SP3  A         10,22       G1
```

SO if I do the same for each row I should get an expected output as :

```
species      family    Events      groups
SP1,SP2,SP3  A         10,22       G1
SP1,SP3      B,E       7           G2
SP1,SP2,SP3  C,D       1,3,4,5,6   G3,G4,G6,G5
SP4          C         7,22        G12
```

Note that SP4 has not been merged with any rows since its group was not present in any other rows.

Does someone have an idea please ?
Thank you very much for your help and time

Here is the dataframe in dic format it can helps:

```
{'species': {1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP2', 5: 'SP2', 6: 'SP3', 7: 'SP3', 8: 'SP3', 9: 'SP4'}, 'family': {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C,D', 4: 'A', 5: 'D,C', 6: 'C', 7: 'E', 8: 'A', 9: 'C'}, 'Events': {1: '10,22', 2: '7', 3: '4,5,6,1,3', 4: '22,10', 5: '6,5,4,3,1', 6: '4,5,3,6,1', 7: '7', 8: '10', 9: '7,22'}, 'groups': {1: 'G1', 2: 'G2', 3: 'G3,G4,G5,G6', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G4,G6,G5,G3', 6: 'G3,G6,G5', 7: 'G2', 8: 'G1', 9: 'G12'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the example DataFrame in a copy/paste format. That's really nice and happends too rarely.

Comment: @moritz it is the least I can do eheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to split the cells on comma, handles them as sets, and finaly join them back. Those are indeed non vectorizable operations, but it leads to (rather) simple code using `apply`.

I would first compute a *containing* group for each row:

```
g = df['groups'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(',')))   # explode into sets
# keep the larger set from g containing the current one and make it back a string
g2 = g.apply(lambda s: ','.join(sorted(
    g[g.apply(lambda x: x.issuperset(s))].max())))
```

With the sample, it gives:

```
1             G1
2             G2
3    G3,G4,G5,G6
4             G1
5    G3,G4,G5,G6
6    G3,G4,G5,G6
7             G2
8             G1
9            G12
Name: groups, dtype: object
```

We can now use it to `groupby` the dataframe and aggregate the groups using the set trick:

```
resul = df[['species', 'family', 'Events']].groupby(g2).agg(
    lambda x: ','.join(sorted(set((i for j in x for i in j.split(',')))))
    ).reset_index().reindex(df.columns)
```

And we get as expected:

```
       species family     Events       groups
0  SP1,SP2,SP3      A      10,22           G1
1          SP4      C       22,7          G12
2      SP1,SP3    B,E          7           G2
3  SP1,SP2,SP3    C,D  1,3,4,5,6  G3,G4,G5,G6
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code but in resul I only get NaN values

Comment: I remove .reindex(df.columns) and i works now